# What algorithms does SQL use?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, sql

Ive always wondered this but never had the chance to research it.

What sort of algorithms are use in SQL? Naturally you search and compare for basic statements, what search algorithms? Sorting? and for other functions like Join's etc.

I know there is no clear cut answer to this questions but the idea is to gather a general idea of what sort of methods SQL uses to carry out its work.

Comment: I don't see how this is subjective or argumentative. Unless different database implimentations are subjective (sort algorithm in MS SQL vs MySql for example)

Comment: I think this quesion "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", as it would take a very large book to start to answer it.

Comment: Ian: There are such books. Is this not the place to recomend them?

Comment: I really don't see how this is argumentative? It may be hard to answer, but it's unanswerable.

Comment: SQL the language makes no assumptions about storage or implementation, hence has no algorithms as such by design. The term `SQL` should _not_ be used to refer to the SQL Server product from Microsoft.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you get a copy of `SQL Server 2008 Internals` by Delaney, Randal, Tripp and more. Excellent book on the internal workings of SQL Server.

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Internals/dp/0735626243/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1289565465&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)

Comment: Seconded! This is where the algorthms are discussed

Comment: Good suggestion, but not really an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at the Microsoft blog about [SQL Server Query Processing](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/bg-p/SQLServer/label-name/SQLServerQueryProcessing), which discusses some SQL Server internals. (The originally linked Craig Freedman blog has been moved there.) Just browse for the interesting topics. If I understood it right, he also wrote some chapter for the already mentioned book series "SQL Server Internals".

You can search the above linked site for the following topics to shed some light on how the different JOIN algorithms work internally:

- Nested Loop Join
- Hash Join
- Merge Join

Answer (score 4):

Joins are performed in three methods:
1. Nested Loop 
2. Hash
3. Merge

Get more about these join methods here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/optimizerjoinmethods/1708/

Answer (score 2):

RDBMS composed of several elements:

- Transaction manager -- manages transactions, as evident from it's name:)
- Physical storage manager -- manages how data stored in underlying file-system(s)
- Query parser/planner/executor -- this is 'user front-end' of database

Each of these elements is essential for any RDBMS and use different set of algorithms to make itself work.

If you interested in internals of RDBMS, get yourself this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Database-Systems-Complete-Book-2nd/dp/0131873253/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873253)

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a superset of relational algebra.  At its basic level, you might want to become familiar with that some.
[Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)

Comment: SQL is perhaps *almost* a superset of relational algebra. In other words, it isn't :). Of course SQL contains lots of non relational stuff: duplicate rows, duplicate column names, nulls. It doesn't have straightforward equivalents of all the relational operators and it gives some strange and inconsistent results (like making the sum of an empty set be null rather than zero). Therefore a certain amount of vagueness, assumption and approximation are required to see SQL as relational. Even then, it's impossible to express the zero degree relations (DUM and DEE) in SQL.